# g++ error unrecognized command line option -mwindows

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a c++ application with a graphical interface and thus I am trying to Implement OpenGL with SDL. I am working on a Ubuntu Subsystem for Windows 10. I already installed the sdl and gl libraries but now when I am compiling my code with 
`g++ -o glpractice glpractice.cpp -Wall $(sdl-confiig --cflags --libs) $(pkgconf gl --libs)` 
 it returns the error 
`g++: error: unrecognized command line option '-mwindows'`
How do I fix that or work around it?

Comment: Whats the output of `sdl-config --cflags --libs` and `pkgconf gl --libs`. One of them is giving the wrong option. I assume it is sdl-config?

Comment: Btw. you should use SDL 2.0 instead of SDL 1.x. SDL 2.0's command is `sdl2-config` or you can use `pkgconfig sdl2 --cflags --libs`.

Comment: You were completely right sdl-config --cflags --libs did actually put out a -mwindows.
Also just by using sdl2-config the problem was solved

Comment: If your command line is a paste get rid of the extra 'i' in sdl-confiig.